# AutoLayout constraints and UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

AutoLayout seems to be battling me every step of the way with a view's size.

I have a view controller that I use for user input, and AutoLayout seems unshakeably determined to make my view 667 pixels high.

I've played with many variants of the layout settings, many content hugging and compression resistance combinations, and no matter what I do, AutoLayout finds a way to stretch the view to 667 pixels high.

I use Reveal, an app that shows layout frames, constraints, etc. (revealapp.com)
and it is showing me that the UIPopoverPresentationController is adding its own autoresizing constraints.

Here's how my view should approximately look when presented...

[image]

Note that even though I have the "Accept" UIButton set to 30 pixels high with a 1000 priority, AutoLayout is still stretching it to meet it's weird 667 pixel high requirement.

When I run the app, here's how my popover looks...

[image]

and when I have Reveal examine the running app, and I narrow it down to the popover, this is what Reveal shows...

[image]

[image]

Note the UIPopoverPresentationController itself has these constraints on it.

How can I control the constraints being put in by the UIPopoverPresentationController ??

Comment: Are you setting the preferred size of the popover before you present it (not in the nib, but in code)?

Comment: @Wyatt ... I'm not setting that, but how would I know what size to set it, because my popover size will vary based on its content.  In the picture above from IB, those two labels above the textbox are dynamically sized based upon their content, making the overall height varied each time it's presented.  How should I calculate the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`boundingRectWithSize(_:options:attributes:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:) of `NSString` to determine what the height of your labels is going to be.

Once you've done that, you can predict what the size of your popover is going to be by adding in whatever extra height your labels create.  You can use that to set the `preferredContentSize` property of the view controller you are presenting.